# Why can't I revisit my own deleted question?

Tags: bug, deletion, deleted-questions, undeletion

I posted a question and then deleted it.  The text block turned red, and the "delete" button changed into "undelete".  Presumably if I click the "undelete" link it will undelete the question; this has worked for me in the past.

But if I visit the same URL in a separate window, I don't see the deleted question or the "undelete" link. Instead, I get "Page Not Found: 
This question was voluntarily removed by the author – that's you!"

I think I should get the page with the deleted text and the option to undelete.

(The particular post in this case was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174286/multiplication-tables-with-all-entries-distinct. I saved the question text locally before I closed the window, so I don't need to have it reinstated, and I don't have any immediate problem that needs to be solved.)

[Addendum: [screenshot is here](http://pic.plover.com/misc/snapshot3.png) in case it helps anyone else figure out what is going on.]

Comment: Are you certain that you were logged-in in the separate window/session? If not, you would see the behavior you described.

Comment: Completely certain. Look at the error message! It says "This question was voluntarily removed by the author – that's you!"

Comment: Ah, I missed the "that's you". I've never seen that message before. Probably it's because you don't have 10k rep, e.g. [see here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126292)

Comment: Do you wish for this particular question to be undeleted? If so, I can cast the final undelete vote.

Comment: Thanks, but I deleted it on purpose.  As I said, I saved the text, I don't need to have it reinstated, and there is no immediate problem that needs to be solved. I would prefer if it were not undeleted, but if it is, I will delete it again until I am ready to repost it myself.

Comment: Looks like an interesting question. I hope you do repost it.

Comment: Thanks, I will.

Comment: Did you ever repost?

Comment: [Here it is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174657/multiplication-tables-with-all-entries-distinct).

Answer (score 9):

See [the meta.SO page on deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/161783), in particular this section:

> Immediately after you delete a question, it will change color to indicate that it is deleted, and an `undelete` link will appear. If you have less than 10k reputation, you will not be able to see the link — or any part of the question — after you leave the page.

Opening a new browser window and trying to view the question, even not having left the question in the original window, appears to function *as if* you were coming back to it after having left.

Comment: Okay, that is an acknowledgement, but not an explanation, or even an excuse.

Comment: I don't design the site :) You can throw your support behind [this meta.SO proposal to let all users see their deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/161783).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see it's yet another case where Jeff Atwood says "It's a bad idea because of *X*", and then everyone else makes the mistake of thinking that they are involved in an discussion, and refutes *X*, and then Atwood ignores the discussion and says "Will not get implemented as long as I am still alive to prevent it from happening." How seriously should I take that?  Have any of those been implemented anyway?

Comment: [Jeff Atwood has left the Stack Exchange company](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/farewell/). I don't have any specific examples in mind of cases where the SE team has given in on things like this, but I would be very surprised if there were none.